# Find the coordinates of the triangle containing the largest number of points

Tags: python

So basically we have a list of x and y coordinate of points and we need to build a triangle, that will contain the largest number of points from this list.

I can check if this point is in the triangle area or not.

```
import math
points = [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 30, 10, 15]

def getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1)
                + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)


def isIn(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y):

    A = getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A1 = getArea(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A2 = getArea(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3)
    A3 = getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y)

    if A == A1 + A2 + A3:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your question is - what are you stuck on?

Comment: Does the triangle need to have a minimum area?

Comment: @RyanFu i don't know how to build an algorithm that will find coordinates of triangle that contains largest number of points

Comment: @AnnZen no, any minimum area

Comment: @qli But then if you have a large triangle you can easily cover all the points.

Comment: @AnnZen I need to build a triangle from points in the list. It doesn't seem to work if I try to build the largest triangle.

Comment: @AnnZen or you think, that I can pick the smallest one point, then the biggest one point, and what will be the third point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) method:

```
from itertools import combinations

points = [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 30, 10, 15]

def getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)

def isIn(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y):
    A = getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A1 = getArea(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A2 = getArea(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3)
    A3 = getArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y)
    return A == A1 + A2 + A3

points = [points[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(points), 2)]

triangle = None
max_points = 0

for c in combinations(points, 3):
    new_points = [p for p in points if p not in c]
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = c
    in_points = sum(1 for x, y in new_points if isIn(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y))
    if in_points > max_points:
        max_points = in_points
        triangle = c

print(triangle)
```

Output:

```
([0, 0], [20, 0], [10, 30])
```

The method, `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`, returns `r` length subsequences of elements from the input `iterable`.

Note the small change in your `isIn` function, where the

```
    if A == A1 + A2 + A3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be replace with just

```
    return A == A1 + A2 + A3
```